# Is it possible to highlight the region uniformly across different sizes/fonts?

Tags: faces, region, highlighting

Highlighting the region when it includes text with different heights/fonts shows gaps and different highlighting heights as follows:

[image: variable highlight height screenshot]

Is there any way of highlighting continuously (no gaps) and consistently (same height)?